# Why does EL >= sometimes give wrong results?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, el

I have this JSP EL expression, which uses the >= comparator. On my development environment I get the result you would expect, namely that 2 >= 188 is false. However, on my staging and production servers apparently 2 >= 188 is true.

Here is the code:

```
</ul>
<p>curPage: ${param.curPage}<br/>
totalPages: ${param.totalPages}<br/>
totalPages - curPage: ${param.totalPages - param.curPage}<br/>
curPage gt totalPages: ${param.curPage >= param.totalPages}<br/>
<p>
```

On my development environment, I get output like this:

```
curPage: 2
totalPages: 68
totalPages - curPage: 66
curPage gt totalPages: false
```

On staging:

```
curPage: 2
totalPages: 181
totalPages - curPage: 179
curPage gt totalPages: true
```

My development environment is running Tomcat 7.0.29, staging is running 7.0.30. The codebases are the same.

The above code is in a file "pagination.jsp" (I know, it should be a .tag), which is included into another jsp like this:

```
<jsp:include page="/widgets/pagination.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="totalPages" value="${actionBean.jbp.totalPages}" />
    <jsp:param name="baseUrl" value="${baseUrl}" />
    <jsp:param name="curPage" value="${not empty param.page?param.page:0}" />
</jsp:include>
```

"jbp.totalPages" is defined as:

private final int totalPages;

and "param.page" is obviously a page parameter.

I suppose there could be a type conversion problem here, between the parameter and the int, but that does not explain why it works on one machine and not the other.

Also, I thought JSP EL did automatic type conversion.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What types are `curPage` and `totalPages`?

Comment: Did you finish the question?  Your second to last sentence ends with "except".  Except what?  You are leaving us hanging.  You mean the same except for the version of Tomcat?

Comment: Sorry, no except, I'm not sure what I was thinking, I removed it.

Comment: @Dancrumb, I double checked, both are ints, I will extend the question with a bit more detail

Comment: A `${param}` value does absolutely not return an int. It refers a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: JSTL and EL are independent concepts.

Comment: I get that ${param} was a String, I just thought (incorrectly) that the EL did type conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those params are evaluated as `String` instead of `Number` (because that's basically what `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` returns). A string value of `"2"` is lexicographically "greater" than any string value starting with `"1"`.

You need to parse them as `Number`. You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<fmt:parseNumber>` for this.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<fmt:parseNumber var="curPage" value="${param.curPage}" integerOnly="true" />
<fmt:parseNumber var="totalPages" value="${param.totalPages}" integerOnly="true" />
... 
<p>
  curPage: ${curPage}<br/>
  totalPages: ${totalPages}<br/>
  totalPages - curPage: ${totalPages - curPage}<br/>
  curPage gt totalPages: ${curPage >= totalPages}<br/>
</p>
```

As to the difference in development versus production environment, this is most likely result of bad testing (not using same test data or maybe even not same test code). There is namely nothing like that changed in Tomcat's EL implementation across the mentioned versions. Only if one of the hands in the comparison is *really* a `Number` and the other is a `String`, then EL will coerce the `String` to `Long`. This is perhaps what is happening in real code.

Comment: this makes sense , only thing confusing is , if they are strings how `totalPages - curPage: 179` is calculated. Is there any thing in EL that parses to integer as - operator is used.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. I just double checked my staging and development environments, and development has 69 pages, whereas staging has 182. So lexicographically, 3 > 69, but 3 < 182. I will try your format suggestion. This seems a bit of a clunky solution, but I don't see an alternative. I will mark this the correct answer after I've verified the solution.

Comment: Note that you don't need to apply this on bean properties which already return `Number` (e.g. `Integer`, `Long`, etc or the equivalent primitives). Only on `${param}`.

Comment: @BalusC, right that makes sense. I've confirmed this was the problem and marked your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

`2 >= 188` is false if the items compared are numbers.

`2 >= 188` is true if the items compared are strings.

You have something different in your two deployments.

Look at the versions of jstl.jar and standard.jar and all the jars, perhaps, in your `tomcat/lib` directories.  Maybe *your* code is the same but there are other differences in dependent libraries?  Somehow the types are different.  It would be unlikely, but not beyond the realm of possibility, that differences in JSP are effecting type inference.

**EDIT**:

This was answered back when the question used 188 (actually 181) for both code examples.  It was since changed to 69 in *one* of the examples.  Now it all makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for the misdirection, your answer was still accurate, so I upvoted it.